# Null =! Object vs Object =! Null

Tags: object, if-statement, conditional-statements

This question is merely a comparison between doing:

```
if(Null != Object){
   /// code here.
}


if(Object != Null ){
   /// code here.
}
```

Can anyone chime in if one conditional statement if superior to the other? Is it case dependent?

I've always used `Object != Null` , but I heard about `Null != Object` today and wondered its differences?

Language agnostic.

--
Thank you to all for chiming in!

Comment: They are identical ...

Comment: @McGarnagle No: identical, they are. That's called a *Yoda Condition* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are logically identical.

I've known people who prefer `Null != Object` and the most common reasons they give are:

- It's less likely to have a bug by using `=` instead of `==` because `Null = <anything>` will result in a compiler error.
- It's unique and cool.

The first reason sort of flies (though I don't think it's worth the hit to code readability), but I'm very much opposed to the second reason.  I personally prefer `Object != Null` for readability.  It's considerably closer to the actual spoken form of the logic being expressed.  (Keep in mind that code is written primarily to be read by humans, and only has a minor secondary purpose of being executed by machines.)

Answer (score 1):

Some people like to use `Null != Object` because it's safer against typos. With the other form, you have a slightly higher risk of writing `Object = Null`, which might be a serious and hard-to-notice error.

Others prefer `Object != Null` because it reads more naturally in English.

But it's completely stylistic -- the two forms are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is really because of C, and usually deals with the equality operator rather than the inequality operator. It's because in C, you have `=` and `==`, which both do completely different things. The problem is it's very easy to mistake one for the other, so you might end up with the following code:

```
int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));
if (i=NULL) {
    ... do nothing?
} else {
    free(i);
}
```

It's a very hard to miss bug, but this code should use the `==` operator. The problem is the compiler sees this as correct, and you've got a bug in your code.

I don't know a reason to do this with the inequality operator though other than style.

Answer (score 0):

Two things still have to be compared.